# Update Multiple Rows with Specific Values and Others With Zero

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

How do I efficiently update multiple rows with particular values for `a_id` 84, and then all other rows set to `0` for that same `a_id`?

**products**

```
p_id    a_id     best 
 111      81       99
 222      81       99
 666      82       99
 222      83       99  
 111      84       99       
 222      84       99
 333      84       99
 111      85       99  
 222      85       99
```

Right now I'm doing this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9142c/2)

```
update products as u set
  best = u2.best
from (values
  (111, 84, 1),
  (222, 84, 2)
) as u2(p_id, a_id, best)
where u2.p_id = u.p_id AND u2.a_id = u.a_id
RETURNING u2.p_id, u2.a_id, u2.best
```

But this only updates the rows within `values` as expected. How do I also update rows not in `values` to be `0` with `a_id` = 84?

Meaning the `p_id` of 333 should have `best` = 0. I could explicitly include every single `p_id` but the table is huge.

- The values set into `best` will always be in order from 1 to *n*, defined by the order of `values`.
- The `products` table has 1 million rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `(p_id, a_id)` is the PK - or at least `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`, this is one way:

```
UPDATE products AS u
SET    best = COALESCE(u2.best, 0)
FROM   products AS p
LEFT   JOIN ( VALUES
   (111, 84, 1),
   (222, 84, 2)
   ) AS u2(p_id, a_id, best) USING (p_id, a_id)
WHERE  u.a_id = 84
AND    u.a_id = p.p_id
AND    u.p_id = p.p_id 
RETURNING u2.p_id, u2.a_id, u2.best;
```

The difficulty is that the `FROM` list of an `UPDATE` is the equivalent of an `INNER JOIN`, while you need an `OUTER JOIN`. This workaround adds the table `products` to the `FROM` list (which is normally redundant), to act as left table for the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. *Then* the `INNER JOIN` from `products` to `products` works.

To restrict to `a_id = 84` additionally, add another `WHERE` clause saying so. That makes `a_id = 84` redundant in the `VALUES` expression, but keep it there  to avoid multiple joins that would only be filtered later. Cheaper.

If you don't have a PK or any other (combination of) `UNIQUE NOT NULL` columns, you can fall back to the system column `ctid` for joining `products` rows. Example:

- [Numbering rows consecutively for a number of tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54992/3684)

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Would you personally use your approach or forpas'? I will benchmark but any feedback is welcome. +1

Comment: You accepted, but I think it's not fully what you want, yet. You *only* want to update rows with `a_id = 84` and not others? Can there be multiple values for `a_id` in the same update or just the one?

Comment: Sorry, I accepted too quickly ;) You're right. I only want to update rows with `a_id = 84`. No, there will only be 1 value (say 84) per update. Please revise your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Now it should do what you are after

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Interesting feedback as well +1

Comment: Wait, it seems like I'm getting all `null` all of a sudden. Your code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9142c/3 .. It was working

Comment: I think it should be `AND    u.p_id = u2.p_id ` instead.

Comment: I forgot that the primary key is on `(p_id, a_id)` - or at least that's what I assume since you are not telling

Answer (score 1):

Remove the condition `u2.a_id = u.a_id` from the ON clause and put it in the assignment with a CASE statement:

```
update products as u set
  best = case when u2.a_id = u.a_id then u2.best else 0 end
from (values
  (111, 84, 1),
  (222, 84, 2)
) as u2(p_id, a_id, best)
where u2.p_id = u.p_id
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct, but 4 minutes behind Erwin's. Any argument for why this approach is superior? I'll certainly benchmark. Thanks

Comment: 4 mins you say (!) is a big difference. If there is no case of cashing the data, then you should definitely  use that. But apart the use of the left join, I don't see any other  reason to dfferentiate the performance so much. Even the use of coalesce() would balance the 2 performances, but mine also has the not so efficient conditional assignment.

Comment: Yes, 4 minutes is nothing but if it was the only differentiating factor then I'd go with Erwin's answer. However, I need only `a_id` = 84 to be updated, not the others.